# Want to send/Receive JMS Message Over internet using hornetq (Possibly with Out Static Ip)

Tags: jms, hornetq

1. I want to send JMS Messages over the internet, and also to receive JMS Messages from other clients. Is that possible without a public (static) IP address?
2. Is there any way to restrict other users from sending JMS message to my system (is there any way to do authentication?) Unauthenticated users should not be able to send JMS messages to my system.
3. How can I enable SSL for my JMS Communication?
4. I use JMS Template to send JMS messages. How can I enable Acknowledgement?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could not produce messages to the server without external visibility (static IP or VPN)
2. Yes you could setup different security policy on the "Security" tab for each user or group.
3. [Goodle have lots of samples](http://www.google.com.ua/search?rls=en&q=ssl%20connection%20to%20Weblogic%20JMS)
4. Created producer or subscriber should have something like:
   ISession session = Connection.CreateSession(Constants.SessionMode.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   [Here full list of Acknowledgement types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13943/WebLogic.Messaging.Constants.SessionMode.html)